# How to keep an empty database the database docker container is started again

Tags: docker, mariadb

There is the following code in my `docker-compose.yml`

```
mariadb:
  image: mariadb:10.8.2
  restart: always
  environment:
    MARIADB_ROOT_PASSWORD: test
    MARIADB_DATABASE: mydb
  ports:
  -  "3306:3306"
  container_name: mariadb
  networks:
  - my-network
```

then I used the following command to start a Docker container

```
docker stop mariadb
docker rm mariadb
docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans mariadb
sleep 15 # wait until database is fully started
docker exec mariadb mysql -u root -ptest -e "CREATE DATABASE product;"
```

After starting the Docker container, i.e. the command `docker-compose up -d --remove-orphans mariadb`, the next command is to create a database called `product`. However, **problem** is that there is the following error `ERROR 1007 (HY000) at line 1: Can't create database 'dictionary'; database exists`

**Question:** Why does the previously created database still exists even though the container and image are removed at the beginning? How to create the container for the second time without an existing database?

Comment: You didn't show us your docker compose file, but presumably you have a volume in there.  Volumes are separate to images and containers, and you need to remove them separately if you want remove all data.  The DB data is in the volume, and if you don't remove it, it is still there when you start it up.

Comment: @Don'tPanic I added the part of `mariadb` service code in `docker-compose.yml`. On base of the given code I don't think there is the volume configured

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are anonymous volumes created with VOLUME in dockerfiles.

It's odd that you mix docker compose with docker commands. Use `docker compose down -v` to remove volumes and anonymous volumes.

Additionally, nowadays consider using `docker compose` v2 instead of now old `docker-compose`.

Comment: Thanks a lot :) tested and all works (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You did not post your compose file, but I can guess that you mapped MariaDB data folder to external volumes, so running again compose, you get the old DB data.

Comment: I added the part of `mariadb` service code in `docker-compose.yml` to the beginning of this question description. On base of the given code I don't think there is the volume configured?